# How to GET '/something' or '/something.html' (Sinatra)

Tags: ruby, sinatra

How can I define a get in Sinatra that will be executed when the server gets either /something or /something.html?

I thought it was...

```
get '/something*' do
end
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regex to match the route, and have an optional group:

```
get %r[^/something(?:\.html)?$] do
  # ...
end
```

Comment: Using this with get something.html, the browser still just loaded the .html page without executing the ruby code I had on the server side.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, are you saying you have an actual `something.html` file in your public directory?

Comment: Yes I do. But I want to execute some ruby code before someone tries to access it.

Comment: In that case you need to serve the HTML file through Sinatra and remove it from your public directory.

Comment: The web server will always try to render a static file on the disk before running your application. There's no way that I know of to avoid this.

Comment: @Takkun, try adding a before filter to run your code prior to serving the static file, e.g. `before /something*/ do`. Read more about [Sinatra's filters](http://www.sinatrarb.com/intro.html#Filters)

Answer (score 0):

It appears Sinatra has a setting to enable static files matching:

> :static - enable/disable static file routes

Visit  [Sinatra Configuring Settings](http://www.sinatrarb.com/configuration.html#__enabledisable_static_file_routes) for details